# mySQL Table ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE 'geodata' (
  'Id' char(16) NOT NULL,
  'Type' smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  'Description' varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  'Url' varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  'Location' point DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('Id')
);
```

> ERROR 1064:
>
> 'Id' char(16) NOT NULL,
>      'Type' smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, at line1.

I don't know whats wrong with my table can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace single quotes with back-ticks i.e `:

```
CREATE TABLE `geodata` (
 `Id` char(16) NOT NULL,
 `Type` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Url` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Location` point DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0736d)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the ' with `. Or just remove the '.