# You have an error in your SQL syntax "line 1"

Tags: php

This has been asked a lot here, but I can't seem to find the problem....

I wanted to submit my FormMail.php to a MySQL database using php.

Getting the error:

Error=Insert failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''FullName', 'EmailAddr', 'contact', 'colors', 'vehicles', 'mesg', 'email', 'rnam' at line 1

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","db79ax4");
if (!$con)
{
Error('database','Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); /* this also exits the script */
}
$FullName = mysql_real_escape_string($aCleanedValues['FullName'],$con);
$EmailAddr = mysql_real_escape_string($aCleanedValues['EmailAddr'],$con);
$contact = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['contact'],$con);
$colors = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['colors'],$con);
$vehicles = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['vehicles'],$con);
$mesg = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['mesg'],$con);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['email'],$con);
$rname = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['rname'],$con);
mysql_select_db("resourcentr", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO johnwork ('FullName', 'EmailAddr', 'contact', 'colors', 'vehicles', 'mesg', 'email', 'rname')
VALUES
('$FullName','$EmailAddr','$contact','$colors','$vehicles','$mesg','$email','$rname')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
Error('database','Insert failed: ' . mysql_error()); /* this also exits the script */
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Any ideas?  Is there something wrong with the above code?
Thanks!

Comment: Use backticks (`) for column names, quotes (') for string literals

Comment: @john I hope this isn't your real password...

Comment: Backticks sure, but those are mostly used for reserved words.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Can't believe that I didn't manage to find any duplicate at all...

Comment: @jeroen They've got to be out there. I feel like I've read this same question many times over. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464437/mysql-table-error-1064) is similar

Comment: This mistake has been done time and time again. Even if a dupe wasn't found, one can't fool the "human" memory ;-) @jeroen

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: ^--« Ah... there we go.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was lazy, just checking the right-hand bar instead of doing a simple search :-)

Comment: @jeroen After a long time of coding (*am sure*), it's a good reason ;-) I'd be lazy too. Edit: I actually had that link as a favorite.

Comment: *Hm....* That `Error(...)`, is a function, right? So much of the *unknown.*

Answer (score 2):

You dont need single quotes `'` around your column names in INSERT INTO statement.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `johnwork` (`FullName`, `EmailAddr`, `contact`, `colors`, `vehicles`, `mesg`, `email`, `rname`)
VALUES
('$FullName','$EmailAddr','$contact','$colors','$vehicles','$mesg','$email','$rname')";
```

Comment: It's good practice to always backtick your field (column) names, so that you don't use an SQL reserved word by accident. Ditto for table names. Single quotes as the OP used, are, in fact, an error.

Comment: better practice to know what the reserved words are; erroneous backticks cause more problems than they solve

Comment: Agreed :) ................

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO johnwork ('FullName', 'EmailAddr', 'contact', 'colors', 'vehicles', 'mesg', 'email', 'rname')
VALUES
('$FullName','$EmailAddr','$contact','$colors','$vehicles','$mesg','$email','$rname')";
```

To this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO johnwork (FullName, EmailAddr, contact, colors, vehicles, mesg, email, rname)
VALUES
('$FullName','$EmailAddr','$contact','$colors','$vehicles','$mesg','$email','$rname')";
```

So your code look like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","db79ax4");
if (!$con)
{
Error('database','Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); /* this also exits the script */
}
$FullName = mysql_real_escape_string($aCleanedValues['FullName'],$con);
$EmailAddr = mysql_real_escape_string($aCleanedValues['EmailAddr'],$con);
$contact = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['contact'],$con);
$colors = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['colors'],$con);
$vehicles = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['vehicles'],$con);
$mesg = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['mesg'],$con);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['email'],$con);
$rname = mysql_real_escape_string($SPECIAL_VALUES['rname'],$con);
mysql_select_db("resourcentr", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO johnwork (FullName, EmailAddr, contact, colors, vehicles, mesg, email, rname)
VALUES
('$FullName','$EmailAddr','$contact','$colors','$vehicles','$mesg','$email','$rname')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
Error('database','Insert failed: ' . mysql_error()); /* this also exits the script */
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Do double check what you did before you get downvoted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You have it backwards. Ticks around column names, quotes around values.

Comment: Not 99%, but 100% sure.

Comment: Hate to tell you I told you so, but I did. Btw, I wasn't the one who downvoted. I always give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right, I've updated the answer.